# nasm assembly for loop

Tags: assembly, nasm

I'm trying to build for loop, but it gives me infinite loop:

```
SECTION .data

i: dd 0
message: db "The number is %d",10,0
SECTION .text

extern printf
global main

main:
    push ebp
    mov ebp, esp

    mov eax, DWORD [i]
    mov ecx, DWORD 10

    L1:
        add eax, DWORD 1
        push eax
        push message
        call printf
        add esp, 8
        loop L1
    mov esp, ebp
    pop ebp
```

nasm gives me the output as `The number is 18` infinitely. But if I put `printf` at the end of the code. It gives me the correct output

```
L1:
    add eax, DWORD 1
    loop L1

push eax
push message
call printf
add esp, 8

mov esp, ebp
pop ebp
```

Anyone knows where I did wrong?

Comment: _ECX_ (your loop variable) needs to be preserved (saved) before calling _printf_ . The C calling convention for 32-bit code on Linux is that _EAX_, _ECX_, and _EDX_ may be destroyed by a function call. If you need any of those registers to be what they were before the call, you will need to save it and then restore it after. You have the same issue with _EAX_

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ecx` is the loop variable. It is typically *caller-saved* - that is, a function like `printf` is allowed to overwrite it and not restore the old value. Therefore, on return from `printf`, `ecx` will be garbage.

To fix this, you can add a `push ecx` before pushing arguments, then a `pop ecx` after the `add esp` removes the function arguments.

Comment: _EAX_ is also being destroyed. It seems they want to print counting from 1 to 10. _EAX_ is being clobbered.

Comment: @MichaelPetch For 32 bit [sans "fast call" that puts the first two args in registers], the ABI has to be the same linux/BSD/winX because printf stops working if the push order were reversed which is only deviation a language could come up with (e.g. IIRC, old fortran _may_ have done this or any lang that has no varargs _could_)

Comment: @SerenaQi: Or, better, use a call-preserved register like `ebx` for your loop counter (with `dec/jnz` instead of the slow `loop` insn).  save/restore ebx at the start/end of `main`, instead of saving/restoring ecx inside your loop.  `printf` has to save/restore `ebx` whether you use it or not (if it wants to use it, which it probably does since it's a complicated function).  Look in the http://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info x86 ABI for details on which registers are which (caller-saved or callee-saved).